# Factoring duty cycle into battery design, give battery life

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, duty-cycle

I have been given the following scenario:

LED output:

•   assume 200 communication codes per 24hrs, and that each of those LED code words take 20msec of processor time to communicate

BLE:

•   connect to devices and then only communicate when it is time to send LED codes.

•   use a menu traversal to re-start the link, BLE communicates the data to pass on the LED and when done LED comms to pass acknowledgement back to Smart Device.

```
            Idle Current        Active Current          On-Time (per day)   
LED             0                 30ma                 200 uses @ 20msec
BLE             0                 20ma                 201 uses @ 50msec
Processor    100uA                130ma                all the time

processor is 3v input
Battery should last 15days

Since rechargeables have approx. 80% capacity end of life and 80% capacity at -20oC. 

Therefore take Estimated battery as 60% of its rated value.
```

I am abit stuck in how I would calculate the estimated battery size in mAh, since the duty cycle is not given.

The duty cycle fomrula im am using is:

```
duty cycle% = (Ton/(Ton+Toff)) *100
```

```
duty c=  (200*20e-3 + 201*50e-3)/ ((200*20e-3 + 201*50e-3)+86400secs) *100
```

I'm getting a value of 0.46% which I'm not sure is right.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate the power consumption in terms of Ah or mAh. This is how the battery is rated.

Comment: yes but how will i go about calculating this

Comment: eg: LED 30mA  200 uses @ 20ms. 
200 times 0.020 = 4 seconds per day or 200/24 * 0.02 = 0.166 seconds per hour
30mA times 0.166/3600 = 0.0014mAh
repeat the calculation for the other loads.

Comment: how do i factor in the processor since its has an all time and idle current?

Comment: Calc the idle and active times separately. What fraction of an hour at 100uA and what fraction of an hour at 110mA?
Eg: if the cpu was always idling at 100uA, then that would be 0.1mAh.

Comment: I am abit confused for  "on all the time" since you cant always be idling and be active at the same time?  is it safe just to assume 130mah + 0.1mah?

Comment: We seem to be doing your homework. Considering it is primary school math, you should be trying a bit harder. According to the 'requirements' the processor takes 20ms 200 times a day at 110mA. So 8.3 times per hour = 0.1666 seconds per hour. 0.009mAh. The idle consumption  would be 0.0999mAh.
1. calculate on time per hour as a fraction.
2. times mA consumption = mAh.